# Which is the most elegant method of identifying Istio internal mesh origin traffic?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I am trying to work out what the most suitable way of identifying if a request came from a specific internal service, or from the outside world (or indeed a different service).

I can write application level code to manage this of course, but was wondering what the simplest solution using Istio would be. The goal is to avoid writing extra layers of code if they're not necessary.

I have JWT on the perimeter for most endpoints, but there are some open (eg. auth).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific scenario, I assumed that you are using http, so you can use Envoy and  two http headers to determine the traffic source from internal or [external](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#http-header-manipulation).

Option 1: With [x-envoy-internal](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-envoy-internal) you will be able to determine whether a request is internal origin or not.

Option 2: You can also check [x-forwarded-for](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#config-http-conn-man-headers-x-forwarded-for) which indicates the IP addresses that a request has generated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I assume the system automatically handles stripping out any faked `x-envoy-internal` during ingress? Or should I write a custom rule for this?

Comment: Correct, the system will classify requests accordingly. No action required. You can have more details about this behaviour by looking at the examples at [https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_conn_man/headers#x-forwarded-for]